# <input type="button" runat="server" /> won't work in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Okay, this may seem silly, but on an ASP.NET .ascx control, I'm trying to use:

```
<input type="button" runat="server" />
```

instead of:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" />
```

And it's not working for me.  This code:

```
<asp:Button id="btnBuyCat" runat="server" Text="Buy Cat"
ToolTip="Click to buy a cat" OnClick="btnBuyCat_Click" EnableViewState="false" />
```

renders the following HTML: *(ignoring naming containers btw)*

```
<input type="submit" id="btnBuyCat" name="btnBuyCat" value="Shopping Cart"
title="Click to buy a cat" />
```

That's mostly fine, except I want **`input type="button"`** not `input type="submit"`.

I tried this code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnBuyCat" name="btnBuyCat" runat="server"
value="Buy Cat" title="Click to buy a cat" onclick="btnBuyCat_Click"
enableviewstate="False" />
```

and get this HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnBuyCat" name="btnBuyCat"" value="Buy Cat"
title="Click to buy a cat" onclick="btnBuyCat_Click" />
```

Unfortunately the rendered button does not work.  Also, I even tried `input type="submit"` just to check, but unless I use the `<asp:Button>` I can't get it to work.  I'm sure it has something to do with the JavaScript.

**Is there a way to use the regular HTML button markup and a `runat="server"` in ASP.NET?**

Comment: try adding an id and try it again

Comment: @Jeroen: Horrible? C'mon, he accepted an answer for 3 out of 5 eligible questions, not 300 out of 500.

Comment: Don't worry Jeroen, if you help me I will regard you with an up-vote and a check mark!  I don't ask many questions, and some of them don't have a solution!

Comment: @jwsample: has an id, look at my code lower in the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you're missing is the `UseSubmitBehavior` attribute, e.g.,

```
<asp:Button id="btnBuyCat" runat="server" Text="Buy Cat" 
UseSubmitBehavior="False" ToolTip="Click to buy a cat" 
OnClick="btnBuyCat_Click" EnableViewState="false" />
```

This will give you a regular button, not a submit button.

Answer (score 4):

To specify an input control runat=server, you must also specify an id. Also the error you get is probably because of js error. onclick event on a standard html control is assuming a script method define, whereas it seems like you wanted to do a postback type operation. Your option is to define a javascript function according to the method name you give to the onclick event, or use __doPostBack method to explicitly trigger postback

```
<input type="button" runat="server" id="btnTest" />
```

Comment: To include postback behaviour on click you will do <input type="button" runat="server" id="btnTest" onclick="doPostBack('btnTest', '');"/>

Comment: +1 Fadrian, this is the answer I was expecting.  I just didn't realize those finer points about ASP.NET yet. *(hangs head in shame)*  However, jball's tip is even more simple for what I am trying to accomplish; thanks though!

Comment: If I get your suggestion working, I might give you the check mark, because technically you're answer explains why my code wasn't working.  But I'm still using jball's because it's easier.

Comment: No worries. Let me know how you went.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
<button type="button" id="btnBuyCat" name="btnBuyCat" value="Shopping Cart"
title="Click to buy a cat"  onclick="btnBuyCat_Click">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
btnBuyCat.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnBuyCat_ServerClick);
```