# How to disregard required="required" in different button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 2 button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnBack" class="btn" type="submit" Text="BACK" runat="server">

 <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" Text="ADD" runat="server" />
```

Button BACK and Button ADD

and 1 Input Text

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtMemberCode" class="input-xlarge"  placeholder="Code"  required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

if I click ADD button and txtMemberCode is empty or null, required field will display this is ok, but

my Problem is when I click BACK button required field also display, I need to ignore either txtMemberCode was null or not.

how can I do that? I try to separate this two button but still the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Change back button type to button because if you use submit as type it will validate the fields inside the form

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" class="btn" type="button" Text="BACK" runat="server">
```

OR use `UseSubmitBehavior` attribute

```
<Button ID="btnBack" class="btn" type="button" Text="BACK" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnBack" class="btn" type="button" Text="BACK" runat="server" 
    onclick="btnBack_Click1"/>
```

but when I check in inspect element

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Main$btnBack" value="Back" id="Main_btnBack" class="btn">
```

this is the output, it was auto replace to  type="submit", still the required field has display.

I got the answer this thread

↓

[<input type="button" runat="server" /> won't work in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445515/input-type-button-runat-server-wont-work-in-asp-net)